# Liferay 6.1 : Mobile theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have created theme for 6.1.20.
Now I want to create theme for Mobile device. I have never created mobile theme before.

I have created one sample-Wap-theme. 
I can see my sample-wap-theme under ContolePanel > Site Pages > Mobile Devices.
I have selected that theme.

but when I switch to different mobile device user agent , I can not see theme changes !!!

Do I need to do any settings for Mobile Device Rule Groups ?

I have read some where about WURFL plugin. Do I need to install it ?

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

As of Liferay 6.1, you must install the WURFL plugin in order to allow the mobile device rules to work.

[This guide is very detailed](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen03-mobile-device-rules-0)